# Помогите создать массив и заполнить его случайными числами от 10 до 99

Tags: php

```
<?php
$arr[];
$arr rand ( int $10 , int $99 );
echo $arr;

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for ($i=0;$i<100;$i++) {
    $arr[] = rand(10,99);
}
```

Comment: <?php
for ($i=0;$i<=10;$i++) {
$arr[] = rand(10,99);
}
print_r ($arr);
$max = max($arr);
$index = array_search($max, $arr);
echo ($index);
$min = min($arr);
echo ($min);














?>

Comment: почему теперь при поиске макс показывает очень большое число?

Comment: Задайте другой вопрос, никто не будет разбирать за код вы написали в комментариях.

Answer (score 0):

PHP 7

```
$a = array_map(function ($e){
    return (int) (ord($e)/255*90+10);
}, str_split(random_bytes(100)));
```